# Are all Serializable classes valid for WCF methods parameters and/or Data Contract members?

Tags: .net, wcf, serialization, remoting

I am in the process of porting some .net remoting code to WCF.

Can I safely assume that all classes that are Serializable and works as .remoting method parameters will work with WCF using the binary message encode?

If not is there a “rule of thumb” that I can use to estimate what problems I will hit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - in general. Be wary however of the default limits for the size of objects (64K members in total). Also be aware of the ['KnownType'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx) attribute for types that are outside of the current assembly.

Comment: KnownType is also used to provide hints for polymorphic return values.